# CSS Print hide all elements but one

Tags: css

I've been searching online for the solution.
I want one thing. when using @media print{...} I want to hide all elements inside body but one. How to do that?
I have class="print" which I don't want to hide, how to hide all that don't have that class?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
@media print {
:not(.print) {
    display: none
}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="print">
  <p>neki lijepi tekst</p>
  <p> test</p>
</div>
<div id="test"> ovo se ne vidi naa printu </div>
<div id="tesft"> ovo se nedsfdf vidi naa printu </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this 'one thing' a child of other elements that you also do not want to print?

Comment: Well, aside from body. Is it a top level DOM element right below body?

Comment: (also: gotta ask, why are you not wanting to let a user print everything?)

Comment: I edited my question. It's not important for them to print everything

Comment: For your edited CSS to work, every thing in the DOM tree that contains the item you want to print has to have the class of 'print' (so every paragraph in your print DIV also has to have a class of `print`--and unless your real example has that simple of HTML structure, I don't think this will be easy to do without some javascript.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to figure it out with jquery to print just specific elements

Comment: Note my jquery answer below. I think that should get you started (if not most of the way there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your DOM structure.

You'll want to hide every top level node (and therefore, their children) with CSS (`display: none`) *except* for the item you want to print *and every parent element* of said item (ie, you don't want to hide the top-level node that contains the item you want to print).

You could set this up (relatively) easily with some javascript--jQuery would help.

- give the item(s) you want to print a class such as 'printThis'
- assign every top level child of BODY a class that is set to `display: none` such as 'doNotPrint'
- find the item you want to print (via the class 'printThis')
- traverse your way up the DOM to each parent removing the class you applied to hide everything (and, possibly, applying the hide class to all siblings in the process)

Not tested, but run something like this on page load to set up your classes:

```
// to start, hide all top level nodes
$('body').children().addClass('doNotPrint')

// now we call this function passing in the 
// item to print
function showItem($node) {
    // remove the 'hide' class. This is moot
    // until we loop to the top level node, at
    // which point this takes affect
    $node.removeClass('doNotPrint');
    // we don't want to print the siblings
    // so we will hide those
    $node.siblings().addClass('doNotPrint')
    // now we check to see if this item has a parent
    // and, if so...
    if($node.parent().length){
        // ...we want to show the parent, hide its 
        // siblings, and then continue this process
        // back to the top of the node tree
        showItem($node.parent());
    } 
}

showItem($('.printThis'));
```

Then your Print CSS would have:

```
.doNotPrint {display: none;}
```

Comment: @Musa I don't think `length` is needed. Either the parent exists or it doesn't.

Comment: Do you know what the `.parent()` returns?

Comment: @musa off to go play with this...:) BRB

Comment: @Musa I take it back, I believe you are correct, we need to put 'length' in there. Good catch!

Answer (score 8):

Hide every child element of the body without a `print` class

```
body > * { display: none }
.print { display: block }
```

once there are no text nodes directly in the bodytis should work.

Comment: As mentioned, this will only work if the item to print is a direct descendent of the body.

Comment: @DA. you mean a child of the body?... and it is.

Comment: Yes, I think 'child' and 'direct descendant' would mean the same thing here. And yes, in the example it is. But it should be noted that that's a key part of the solution is all.